# Leantime Project Management can't switch language to Italian

Tags: configuration, project, default

I'm unable to switch default language to Italian in Leantime project management. Changed `configuration.sample.php` to `configuration.php` and modified default language with `it-IT` but interface is still in english. Everything else is working. Don't understand wht I'm doing wrong...

Apache/2.4.58 (Unix) 
PHP 8.2.16  
Leantime 2.4.8

[image]